# How to approach this, morphing HTML form

Tags: java, html, css, forms, business-logic

Hello I'm unsure of how to approach this Logic regarding a form. So, the form is big, more than 20 fields I know that is considered a "bad practice" and forms should be minimal, but thats how the client wants it so no arguing, anyways the form will take orders , but there are different order types (more specifically 5) the "normal type" has all fields and the other types have some fields and some not, at the moment the order type is extracted from a `get` paramater and based on its value some fields are displayed and other are not, the problem is that when the type of order contains less fields than the "normal" type the form looks ugly liked if someone chopped some parts instead of fitting naturally, so here's a small list of what I've thought (I'm using `JSP` by the way):

- Define an individual style for each order type that means using the JSTL to load a different CSS stylesheet in the headers.
- Another way would be to make a saparate HTML page for each type of order each page will contain the fields that the order type requires and will have their own CSS file.
- Use a `c:choose` for each order type and include the fields in each `c:when` block. I don't like this very much because it means repeating some fields in each block.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered disabling/enabling fields based on the order type?
How about using a multiple page form?

When you say the CSS is messed up what exactly happens?

If I read your question properly the problem is a purely CSS one - so I'm adding the tag to the question.  Can you perhaps post your CSS?  Specifically how each of your forms fields are currently shown/hidden.

You might also want to let your client know that (unless making use of ajax) that users may (and will) lose data if they navigate away from such a large form by mistake.

Comment: The problem with enabling/disabling fields is that the can be re-enabled by Google Chrome's Inspect Element feature. And I picked the wrong words, when I say "messed css" I mean it looks wrong and I don't like it. Great Advice on warning users.

Comment: Well like all good software you need to ALSO perform validation server side. You can never trust anything the browser provides exactly just because they may well have some tools such as Chromes Inspect Element

Comment: Yes I know that I do perform server side validation, but I consider that if the fields aren't going to be needed why show them.